# How to make textboxes read-only when called from one controller but not read-only when called from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have one view that is used to create and edit my model. For the edit action the fields on the page are automatically populated with the data from the model and can be edited and then saved. I'd like a similar action from my controller that populates the fields with the data for a sort of "View" page. I read that I can add the htmlAttribute `@readonly="readonly"` to my textboxes but is there a way that I can append this attribute to the textboxes (or something easier) only when the view is called from this action? I'm not sure what code is relevant here, more of a conceptual question, but here's some code just in case:

The view that I want to use for all three functions (create, edit, and view) is called "Create.cshtml" and is full of:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.SubmissionNumber)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project.SubmissionNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.SubmissionNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

and a few dropdown menus:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.Status)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.Status,
                      Model.Statuses,
                      "--")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I won't include the whole view because it's very repetitive. Picture a bunch of textboxes and dropdown menus just like that.

My Create action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new ProjectClearanceApp.Models.ProjectViewModel();
    var statuses = GetAllStatuses();
    var divisions = GetAllDivisions();
    var branches = GetAllBranches();
    var project_types = GetAllProjectTypes();
    var states = GetAllStates();

    model.Statuses = GetSelectListItems(statuses);
    model.Divisions = GetSelectListItems(divisions);
    model.Branches = GetSelectListItems(branches);
    model.ProjectTypes = GetSelectListItems(project_types);
    model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);

    return View(model);
}

// POST: Projects/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProjectName,ProjectDescription,DateReceived,EffectiveDate,ExpirationDate,GeneralContractor,ProjectTerm,ProjectType,SubmissionNumber,PolicyNumber,Status,Underwriter,Division,BrokerCity,TAName,Branch,FirstNamedInsuredAddress,FirstNamedInsured,ProjectAddress")] Project project)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (project.ProjectID <= 0)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var model = new ProjectViewModel();
    model.Project = db.Projects.Find(project.ProjectID);

    var states = GetAllStates();
    var branches = GetAllBranches();
    var divisions = GetAllDivisions();
    var project_types = GetAllProjectTypes();
    var statuses = GetAllStatuses();

    model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);
    model.Branches = GetSelectListItems(branches);
    model.Divisions = GetSelectListItems(divisions);
    model.ProjectTypes = GetSelectListItems(project_types);
    model.Statuses = GetSelectListItems(statuses);

    return View(model);
}
```

All of those `GetAll_____s()` and `GetSelectListItems(_____)` are to fill the enums that populate the dropdown menus.

My Edit action (shockingly similar):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var model = new ProjectViewModel();
    model.Project = db.Projects.Find(id);

    if (model.Project == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var states = GetAllStates();
    var branches = GetAllBranches();
    var divisions = GetAllDivisions();
    var project_types = GetAllProjectTypes();
    var statuses = GetAllStatuses();

    model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);
    model.Branches = GetSelectListItems(branches);
    model.Divisions = GetSelectListItems(divisions);
    model.ProjectTypes = GetSelectListItems(project_types);
    model.Statuses = GetSelectListItems(statuses);

    return View("Create", model);
}

// POST: Projects/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjectDescription,DateReceived,EffectiveDate,ExpirationDate,GeneralContractor,ProjectTerm,ProjectType,SubmissionNumber,PolicyNumber,Status,Underwriter,Division,BrokerCity,TAName,Branch,FirstNamedInsuredAddress,FirstNamedInsured,ProjectAddress")] Project project)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (project.ProjectID <= 0)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
        } else
        {
            db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var model = new ProjectViewModel();
    model.Project = db.Projects.Find(project.ProjectID);

    var states = GetAllStates();
    var branches = GetAllBranches();
    var divisions = GetAllDivisions();
    var project_types = GetAllProjectTypes();
    var statuses = GetAllStatuses();

    model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);
    model.Branches = GetSelectListItems(branches);
    model.Divisions = GetSelectListItems(divisions);
    model.ProjectTypes = GetSelectListItems(project_types);
    model.Statuses = GetSelectListItems(statuses);

    return View("Create", model);
}
```

I'm assuming the "View" action that I want to be read-only should be similar to the "GET" Edit/Create actions, but I don't know what I need to add to make those textboxes read-only.

Comment: as far as i understand, you have three actions: Create, Edit, and View. Therefore, you must have three views: Create, Edit and View. Thus, you can set the readonly property to the textboxes you want in the view that you want. As far as i udnerstand, this is best practice, i.e. separation of concerns. So you are actually better of having three views and not recycling the views for different actions

Comment: Your read-only view for a `View()` method (typically named `Details()`) should be just that - rendered as text only. It should not have form controls

Comment: @JustLearning that would be incredibly redundant to have three separate views, all with exactly the same code, minus a few small changes here and there.

Comment: The reason you have three views is to address three different business processes separately without affecting one another. So if you need to make changes it will take less time. If you have redundant code, then you need to create a function/method in your controller so it can be reused

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that but I'm trying to build an application where the Create, Edit, and View methods all look identical, except the View method needs to be read only. Are you saying this is not possible, or it is just bad practice?

Comment: @JustLearning If I have three separate views that look exactly the same but function differently, how would that be easier to make changes to? That's incredibly redundant when I can just use the same view for multiple actions. My code isn't redundant as it is... your suggestion would make it redundant.

Comment: actually that is exactly what you should do in your controller. Assign a single method in your controller to build your model, then get the model in your controler actions.

Comment: Just bad practice - why would you generate all that extra html and then send it all to the server. Your also allowing a malicious user tosubit a form from that view. And a details view will typically include elements that an create or edit will not, for example a link to edit the data (which may or may not exist depending on the user permissions)

Comment: And as a side note, your create and edit views appear to contain dropdownlists, and there is no such thing as a readonly `<select>`

Comment: you dont have to have 3 different views, and have a single view. The problem is if your requirements change you wil spend more time trying to squeze them in, if you have a single view.

Comment: Just to get this straight: @StephenMuecke and @JustLearning ... you guys are telling me that the best way to achieve this is to COPY my `Create.cshtml` view to a new view, add readonly attributes to all of my textboxes, and use that? Two separate views that are practically identical? And claiming that this is best practice?

Comment: No I did not suggest that. Your `Details.cshtml` view should just include `<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>` or `<div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeProperty)</div>` elements to generate text only, not form controls.

Comment: And I have just noticed you using a view model in the view but binding to a data model. Change the parameter to `ProjectViewModel model` and remove that ridiculous `[Bind]` attribute then map the view model to an instance of the data model and save.

Comment: Well then you are clearly misunderstanding what I'm asking. I understand that you might think that is best practice, but I want my `View` method to generate the exact same page as the `Create` and `Edit` methods, but with read only text boxes instead. If I have to copy the code to a new view and add the read only attributes, then I will do that, but I do not want to simply display the data on a page in plain text, I want it to look identical.

Comment: Also there is a `@disabled` attribute for DropDownLists to make them read only

Comment: Please listen to @StephenMuecke.  He's speaking the truth.

Comment: Do not confuse behavior and appearance. Your can style a `<div>` element to look like a textbox if that is really what you want to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke again if I made a new View for my "view" method using styled divs that is designed to look just like the View for my "edit" and "create" methods, why would I not just copy and paste the code and add `@readonly="readonly"` to all of the textboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to achieve what I actually wanted was I added a `bool ReadOnly` to my ViewModel and wrapped all of my textboxes and dropdownlists in an if/else statement, like this:

```
@if (Model.ReadOnly)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project.SubmissionNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
}
else
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project.SubmissionNumber)
}
```

and this:

```
@if (Model.ReadOnly)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.Status,
                          Model.Statuses,
                          "--",
                          new { @disabled = "disabled" })
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.Status,
                          Model.Statuses,
                          "--")
}
```

and now I can reuse the exact same view for all three methods without needing to copy paste code.

Comment: This isn't a great idea because you now have untestable logic in your views.